# Installing a package with apt-get for a single user

Tags: apt, package-management

Is it possible to install a package for just the current user (placing files in locations that the user can write to, such as their home directory)?

Comment: [Is there any way to get APT to install packages to my home directory?](http://serverfault.com/questions/23734/is-there-any-way-to-get-apt-to-install-packages-to-my-home-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to install a package in a way that it would run correctly. The closest thing you could get to this is running *apt-get* inside a virtual machine or LXC container run by a normal unprivileged user. If you want to just unpack the .deb package, you can use `dpkg -x archive.deb target_directory`, but the installation scripts will not be run, and it will not be installed to the filesystem root.

Comment: As I thought. Compiling the sources directly will be necessary in any of these cases.

Comment: If you run Ubuntu in a VM or LXC container you can install binary packages to the root of the VM disk (which is either a file or directory in the host).